# Parallel call to Elasticsearch in c#

Tags: elasticsearch, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I am trying to make a parallel call to Elasticsearch index for multiple queries and aggregate the result, using `Parallel.ForEach`.

My code:

```cs
private static List<SearchResponse<dynamic>> SearchQueryInParallel(string indexName, string lang, string[] eQueries)
{

    var result = new List<SearchResponse<dynamic>>();
    var exceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();

    object mutex = new object();

    try
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(eQueries,
            () => new SearchResponse<dynamic>()
            , (q, loopState, subList) =>
            {

                var x = LowlevelClient.Search<SearchResponse<dynamic>>(indexName, $"article_{lang}", q);
                subList = x;
                return subList;

            }, subList =>
            {
                lock (result)
                    result.Add(subList);
            }
        );
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        foreach (var e in ae.InnerExceptions)
        {
            exceptions.Enqueue(e);
        }
    }

    if (exceptions.ToList().Any())
    {
        //there are exceptions, do something with them
        //do something?
    }

    return result;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that `sublist` in the above case is `long`.
It gives me the following error:

> Can not convert from SearchResponse to long.

The same thing is working when I used without multithreading, the code is:

```cs
var items = new List<dynamic>();

var searchResponse = lowLevelClient.Search<SearchResponse<dynamic>>(elasticIndexName, $"article_{languageCode.ToLowerInvariant()}", query);

foreach (var document in searchResponse.Body.Documents)
{
    items.Add(document);
}
```

Any help, please? If somebody has any other way to achieve the parallel call and aggregating data from returned values would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to make the same but without parallelism involved? Type conversion error  could be solved easier if we don't have to deal with optimization code. If you have the sequential counterpart then can you please share with us as well?

Comment: yes, sure, I'll share that. It's working without parallelism. But I have to call it multiple times for different queries which are in the loop which is taking lot of time, I am turning to a parallel call to reduce the time.

Comment: Without multithreading, I used the following code and added to an object of List<dynamic> 

 var searchResponse = lowLevelClient.Search<SearchResponse<dynamic>>(elasticIndexName, $"article_{languageCode.ToLowerInvariant()}", query);
                    foreach (var document in searchResponse.Body.Documents)
                    {
Items.Add(document);
}

"Items" is an object of List<dynamic>

I want to achieve the same result by running multiple queries and aggregating the result items

Comment: Can please edit your question to include the sync version as well? It is really hard to read the code without indentation :D

Comment: Edited the question to add the working code without multi threading

Comment: Does the lowLevelClient have async Search? If so then it would be quite easy to run several queries concurrently. You can run a lots of non-blocking async I/O operations through your network driver but only just a bunch of (as many cores your machine has) CPU bound operations. Parallel.XYZ were designed for CPU bound operations, while your search queries are definetly I/O bound.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know there is an async version of the LowLevelClient search, but in our case, we are not the consumer of data we are getting here, but a Middleware API, We store data into Elasticsearch Index and search index only on a API request, curate the response and send as API response.

Comment: @ArvindKmar If you look at the documentation of the [Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netcore-3.1) then you can see it has 20+ overloads. Some accepts an `Action` as the `body` parameter, some accepts a `Func`.  Try to use different overload which better suite for your needs.